# How to move custom icons from parent theme to the child theme

Tags: customization, child-theme, icon

I have two sets of custom font icons that from my understanding are being loaded by two php files of the theme that i am making a child theme of : **admin-style.php** & **icons.php**

**admin-style.php :**

```
<?php 
$admin_style = sanitize_text_field('

@font-face{
    font-family:"Stefanos";
    src:url("' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Stefanos/Stefanos.woff") format("woff"),url("' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Stefanos/Stefanos.ttf") format("truetype");
}
*[data-ico-stefanos]:before{
    font-family: Stefanos;
    content:attr(data-ico-stefanos);
}
.bt_bb_icon_preview.bt_bb_icon_preview_stefanos{
    font-family: Stefanos;
}', array() );
```

**icons.php :**

```
<?php
$icons = sanitize_text_field('

@font-face {
        font-family: "Stefanos";
        src: url("' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Stefanos/Stefanos.woff") format("woff"), url("' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/Stefanos/Stefanos.ttf") format("truetype");
}
*[data-ico-stefanos]:before {
        font-family: Stefanos;
        content: attr(data-ico-stefanos);
}', array() );
```

What is happening is that

• when i move those two files containing the custom font icons loading code, to the child theme, the icons are not being loaded. The icons code works only when those two php files are in the parent theme. Even in the form of ***get_parent_theme_file_uri*** instead of ***get_template_directory_uri*** it works only when is in the parent theme.

• When moving the **admin-style.php** & **icons.php** to the child theme, and keeping the font files folder (/fonts/Stefanos) in the parent theme, the custom icons are not being loaded

• When moving the **admin-style.php** & **icons.php** and the font files folder (/fonts/Stefanos) to the child theme, the custom icons are not being loaded.

• Using ****get_stylesheet_directory_uri**** instead of ****get_template_directory_uri**** it doesnt work either, no matter where the php and the font files are, in the parent or the child theme

What's keeping the custom font icons from loading when placed in the child theme?

Comment: You can't just copy arbitrary files into a child to replace them. That's not how it works. If you copy admin-style.php to the child theme nothing is going to happen if the parent theme is including it from the parent theme. What to do instead depends on how and where these files are being used by the parent theme. You may need to unhook them from a hook and then use the child theme to hook the child theme versions back in, but it's not possible to say based on the code provided.

Comment: I appreciate the info. If there are related hooks, the only place to be found are in the parent theme's functions.php, right ?

Comment: Yes, but functions.php can also `include` or `require` other PHP files, so the relevant code could also be in those.

Comment: Here are the parent theme files i could spot that appear to control the loading of icons, just in case someone is interested to take a look.  

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EE1-vt2um2Z5BzWoH3rcVRz73gTDwsFH?usp=sharing